# Ubuntu laptop boots in EFI Shell instead of OS

Tags: command-line, uefi, bootloader, boot-repair

starting up my laptop this morning running Ubuntu goes directly into EFI shell. Not sure what this failure might be. I have reset a few times and gone into the Boot Manager to see anything unusual in the settings, looks ok.

Is there commands I can run to force my OS to start or could this be another error I need to look for!

also there seem to be no map in EFI shell so I cannot see my drives  –
[image]

Comment: Have you check and confirmed "Ubuntu" is selected in the Boot menu?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I'm in Boot Manager after exit in EFI Shell and can only see Boot Override which is Ubuntu. I have also used hard disk instead of USB-LAN in Boot sequence order and have rebooted, still same issue just boots into EFI Shell EFI Shell version 2.50 current mode 1.1.2 map:cannot find the required map name

Comment: Downloaded Boot-repair, using Rufus made the USB ISO bootable. Ran and there are no boot issues found by Boot-Repair. Installed Boot Update from here, shutdown removed USB goes back to EFI Shell no luck, no sector errors on the hard disk either.

Comment: also there seem to be no map in EFI shell so I cannot see my drives 'Shell> map map:cannot find required map name'

Answer (score 0):

[image]I opened the laptop and tightened all connectors to the motherboard. Powered on and even though I am booted into the EFI shell, I can now see fs0 and launch grubx64.efi into the OS ubuntu.......Looks to be that there was a connector loose on the motherboard, even so now the disk is seen and I can map, why I am still booting into EFI?